# How do I use VBA to find out where a connection is being used if at all?

Tags: excel, vba, powerquery

The issue is that, excel connections and queries can sometimes become unlinked, or fail to refresh due to one error or another.  The issue is when i am attempting to check for this disconnect, there doesn't appear to be a method to differentiate between connections with table and connection only.

I've attempted using source like this,

```
    Dim sourceConnection  As Object: Set sourceConnection = ActiveWorkbook.Connections(1)
    ThisWorkbook.RefreshAll
    Application.CalculateUntilAsyncQueriesDone
    Sheets(1).Activate
    
    
    ' Add code to determine the worksheet that is using the connection
    
    If sourceConnection.OLEDBConnection.Source = "" Then
        MsgBox "The sourceConnection is connected with only a connection."
    Else
        MsgBox "The sourceConnection is linked to a table somewhere on the workbook."
    End If
```

Tablename

```
    Dim sourceConnection  As Object: Set sourceConnection = ActiveWorkbook.Connections(1)
    ThisWorkbook.RefreshAll
    Application.CalculateUntilAsyncQueriesDone
    Sheets(1).Activate
    
    
    ' Add code to determine the worksheet that is using the connection
    
    If sourceConnection.OLEDBConnection.Tablename = "" Then
        MsgBox "The sourceConnection is connected with only a connection."
    Else
        MsgBox "The sourceConnection is linked to a table somewhere on the workbook."
    End If
```

or even command text

```
    Dim sourceConnection  As Object: Set sourceConnection = ActiveWorkbook.Connections(1)
    ThisWorkbook.RefreshAll
    Application.CalculateUntilAsyncQueriesDone
    Sheets(1).Activate
    
    
    ' Add code to determine the worksheet that is using the connection
    
    If sourceConnection.CommandText = "" Then
        MsgBox "The sourceConnection is connected with only a connection."
    Else
        MsgBox "The sourceConnection is linked to a table somewhere on the workbook."
    End If
```

of the three, command text is the only one that compiles and runs, but fails to provide the desired information as the text only looks at the commands being followed by the connection, and does not reference anything regarding the tables it may be used by.

Comment: How do you define `Connections`,`Tablename`,`CommandText`? `Set sourceConnection = ActiveWorkbook.Connections(1)` did you check the connection in locals is it exists? can you add a screenshot of locals window before exit form your function?

Comment: Connections is not made visible by the locals, and its members(or possible members) are also not showing within the locals.  simply being displayed as an Object.  the definition of this object is handled in the back end black box of excel / Microsoft vba. [link](https://imgur.com/a/PcBxpiY) @Mik

Comment: the object browser is here as well[link](https://imgur.com/a/JU8sMBb),  admittedly hadn't had the thought to look here until your question produced no results @Mik

Comment: Hi, which one runs? Frankly speaking, it's hard to advice something valuable. In a case like that I'd try to find an alternative solution.

Comment: The command text does pull the string from the connection that tells it where to get the data, in this case it outputs the drop folder i am pulling data from.  Tablename does not appear to be a proper member of the connection object @Mik